# How to display both a link and link name from a database using rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I would like to display a link from the database and also the link name also saved in the db.I am using rails 4 and haml. Any ideas how I can achieve this? I have tried both of these with no luck so far:     `%td= link_to @essential.catalog_url_type, @essential.catalog_url` and

```
%td
  %a{:href => catalog.catalog_url} {{catalog.catalog_url_type}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it using string interpolation. `%td= link_to catalog.catalog_url_type, "#{catalog.catalog_url}"`

Answer (score 1):

```
= link_to(@foo.link_name, @foo.link_url)
```

@foo is your db object defined in your controller and link_name and link_url are the attributes where the name and link are stored in your db.

Comment: Please try to explain the logic behind your answer. Code-only answers may not be as useful/intuitive to people getting started with the technology.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if I'm reading the question wrong. Is catalog_url_type the text you want to show?

Have you tried:

```
%td
  %a{ :href => catalog.catalog_url, :title => catalog.catalog_url_type }
```

Answer (score 0):

`= link_to @essential.catalog_url_type, @essential.catalog_url`

I noticed that there your `=` seems to be attached to the `%td`, I would try putting the link on the line below.  I'm not a HAML user so I can't say for sure.  Plus it's hard to see what is going on with out the model and controller.

What errors are you getting or what is happening when you click the link.

Comment: HAML is white space dependent and therefore you must have the = to the %td.